# Can't connect to RN42-XV bluetooth module through iOS app

Tags: ios, external-accessory

I am currently working on an iOS app written in Swift 3 which has to send data to a (MFi) bluetooth module over a serial port connection using the External Accessory Framework. The bluetooth module in question is the [RN42-XV](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11601)

I am testing on an iPhone 7, and the phone can connect to the bluetooth module through the bluetooth section in the settings app. When I try to connect through my app I get EABluetoothAccessoryPickerError number 1, resultNotFound (https://developer.apple.com/reference/externalaccessory/eabluetoothaccessorypickererror.code)

I read that I'm getting this error because I need to add the bluetooth module's protocol to my Info.plist under the "Supported external accessory protocols" header. If this is true, does anyone know where I can find this protocol string? I've already contacted the bluetooth module's developers but haven't gotten a response yet.

Comment: Only the MFi licensee can tell you what identifier they have used; Have they created a device using the RN42-XV?  The RN42-XV itself is not MFi compliant

Comment: The chip is supposed to be MFi from what I've been told. And the iPhone does detect it and allows me to connect to it. Where did you find information about it not being MFi?

Comment: Nowhere on the page you linked to, does it say that it is MFi compliant.  In order to create an MFi device a company must enter into a license agreement with Apple and submit the device for certification.  It would be difficult, if not impossible, for a company like SparkFun to get a general purpose module such as that licensed by Apple as .  An MFi device needs to include an Apple ID chip.  The RN42-APL module is available to MFi licensees from Microchip.  A BLE module will let you use CoreBluetooth without needing any MFi membership, but has lower data throughput

Comment: The RN42-XV bluetooth module is the same as the RN42 module,  if you look [here](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/RN42) you can see that under features it lists "Supports Bluetooth data link to iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch".

I also can't seem to find anything about the RN42-APL module, could you link it for me?

Comment: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005113B.pdf

Comment: Thanks, guess I should get that module then.
One more question, how come my RN42-XV module can be detected and connected to by the iPhone if it is not an APL device?

Comment: Because iOS supports legacy Bluetooth.  It is only after the pairing process that the MFi protocols kick-in to discover (or not) the MFi services.  You will need to [become a member of the MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) before you can purchase an RN42-APL

Comment: Wait, I thought I only needed to join the MFi program if I wanted to develop Apple accessories? I'm only creating an app that interacts with an MFi accessory.

Comment: If you want to interact with an existing MFi accessory then the developer/manufacturer of that accessory needs to provide their protocol details and add your app to their list of approved apps with Apple.  The RN42-XV module you linked to is not an MFi accessory.

Comment: Oh okay, so, correct me if I'm wrong. I need to purchase an RN42-APL bluetooth module and I'll need to get the protocol from the manufacturer, and have the manufacturer whitelist my app's bundle id?

Thanks for your help so far! It's highly appreciated

Comment: The manufacturer will purchase RN42-APL modules and embed them in their MFi accessory.  They need to provide you with the details to put in your app to allow the external accessory framework to find the device.  In this case you won't need to purchase any Bluetooth modules.

Comment: Aah, got it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for the "Supported external accessory protocols" string everywhere to be able to communicate with my RN42. Did you find it ? thanks!